# Adding button in pygame and said color "green" is undefined variable

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a small game using pygame. I'm trying to add a rectangle button on the screen and I'm using the pygame drawing function, which is

```
 pygame.draw.rect(background, green, [20, 20, 50, 20], 0)
```

However, in the color part, it said that "green" is a undefined variable.

[image: It said that "green" is a undefined variable]

I don't know why this happens, since "green" is not a variable, it's the color of the button. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
 Update: this problem is fixed and I updated the function in this post that is works.

Comment: Do you know what format the color is supposed to be in?

Comment: I saw many people using this format, and I also try many format but all didn't work, I'm confused now. I don't know which one is the correct format.

Comment: The code you're showing doesn't match the error in the image.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and test. If you haven't defined a variable with the name `green`, then you can't use it as an argument for `pygame.draw.rect`.

Comment: This problem is fixed and I just updated the function that work,

Comment: and yes I need to define the color first.

Comment: In future, [don't post images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) as they are never useful for us, because the code can't be copied and pasted. Also, in future, [post all the exception details](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define green because the variable there is an RGB

As stated here: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html

```
green = (  0, 255,   0)
pygame.draw.line(screen, green, ...)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, [75, 10, 50, 20], 2)
```

Try my new edit

Comment: I'm adding the defined section, however, it still don't work, it said"rect argument is invalid", However, I see many people using this function in this format, I'm confuse now, I use so many format but all didn't work, I don't know which one is the correct format.

Comment: Try my new edit your rect arguments are invalid. The format is
(place, color, position = [75,10,50,20] play with those arguments, and width)

Comment: I just tried your new edit, and I couldn't see the button on the screen, so I think it's a fail?

Comment: You need to define the third parameter as the position of the rectangle. Please refer to the documentation of pygame i linked.

It might be that the rectangle is in a wrong position or the screen is not yet initialized. I cannot know without the full code how to figure it out.
But the rectangle is being rendered somewhere if python didn't throw an error on the line

Comment: I fixed some error and it works now! thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You try insert color in the RGB format? e.g: `(0, 0, 255)`

Comment: I'm adding the defined section, however, it still don't work, it said"rect argument is invalid", However, I see many people using this function in this format, I'm confuse now, I use so many format but all didn't work, I don't know which one is the correct format.